# How to upload image to web (firestore) - Flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

so i've tried to upload an image to firestore, but it gives me the error Unsupported operation: _Namespace.
Here's my method:

```
File pickedImage;
  Future<Uri> uploadPic() async {
    FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

    StorageReference reference = _storage.ref().child("profile_pictures/");

    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(pickedImage);

    Uri dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();

    return dowurl; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a name to the file you want to save:

```
StorageReference reference = _storage.ref().child("profile_pictures/ –add Name here –");
```

You might also remove the `/` that comes after `profile_pictures`, if you don‘t want to add another reference

Comment: Do I have to write the extension in the name? "profile_pictures/test.png" or just "profile_pictures/test" ?

Comment: @AlexandreMercier no, you don't have to use '.png' at the end of the file name. Firebase is managing that for you.